# "np.nan" isn't converted properly but "None" is

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In the following code I generate some data containing the value np.nan:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 20
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": np.random.choice(["dog","cat",np.nan],n), "y": range(0,n)})
```

Subsequently I check for missing values via the function pd.notnull and this does not indicate that there are any missing values:

```
pd.notnull(df["x"])
```

Ok, the reason is that the np.nan used in the creation got somehow translated into a string "nan". But why? For instance, if I substitute the None value in the expression for np.nan, i.e. if I create the data via np.random.choice(["dog","cat",None],n), then everything works.

Can someone explain why np.nan isn't properly converted? And in general: How do I create random missing data for a string column without using np.nan or the None object?

Comment: Why are you mixing strings with the floating point value NaN?

Comment: output for `np.random.choice` is array , and it have one value type

Comment: Ok I mix types: But even the userguide example does it (see inserting missing data section): https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html. Further, the fact that output is array with one value type does not seem to answer why the example works when using None-value.

Answer (score 2):

`np.random.choice` creates a numpy array, which can only hold one type of data, you can try to set the datatype manually with `dtype=float` (nan is a float), but that does not work with the string values.

```py
options = np.array(["dog","cat",np.nan], dtype=float) # ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'dog'
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": np.random.choice(options,n), "y": range(0,n)})
```

edit: you can set dtype to object, then the code will work:

````py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 20
options = np.array(["dog","cat",np.nan], dtype=object)
print(options)
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": np.random.choice(options,n), "y": range(0,n)})
print(df)```
````

Answer (score 1):

As for creating random missing data for a string column, you can use [`.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```py
n = 20  
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": np.random.choice(["dog","cat"],n), "y": range(0, n)})  
mask = pd.Series(np.random.rand(n) < 0.33) # change to any fraction of missing values
df['x'] = df['x'].mask(mask)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But its kind of puzzling to me, why all these steps are required to achieve something very simple. In R I could simply set a NA-value which is handled properly from the beginning.

Comment: @P.Jo, well, I'd simply use `None`, but you explicitly asked how to do it without `None`.

Comment: Ah ok - I just thought that there is maybe a different type of numpy/pandas-NA value for string data. But if that is not true, then I use None. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: In `numpy`, strings have a distinct `dtype`, such as `U32` in your `choice` example.  The float `np.nan` is converted to its string representation.  `pandas` uses Python strings and `object` dtype for its columns.  `None` also makes the array `object` dtype (throw a `None` in your `choice` list to see that).  So a Series can have a mix of strings, `np.nan`, None, and numbers.  `df.isna()` can detect both `None` and `np.nan`, but doesn't distinguish the `'nan'` string.